# Multiple select inputs in Angular 15 reactive form with shared filtered options

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am building an Angular 15 reactive form with dynamically generated select elements to let a user map columns for a .csv import.

I would like to filter all the select elements in this manner:

1. User chooses an option in one select element.
2. The list of available options for all other select elements has that option removed.
3. When the previously chosen option is unselected, the list of available options is updated to have the option added back in.

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbjgg3?file=src%2Fmain.ts) to better demonstrate what I am trying to accomplish.

I can't get my head around how to manage the filtering of select elements by updating them without destroying what the user has already selected in other elements. Do I need to manage 3 different Arrays? An original list, current list, new list?

Any help is appreciated.

---

**Edit 04/11/2023:** The StackBlitz referenced above has been updated with a potential solution. If someone sees a way to streamline this solution, I would appreciate any input. Thank you.